# How can make a function accepts X from 0, 1 ... N and returns Y from shuffle( 0, 1 ... N )?

Tags: random

I am searching for a function which has input a number X from 0, 1, 2, 3....N. Its result should be Y which belongs to a permuted version of the input's set.

The results must be unique and thus all of them are generated. Now, I am aware / don't mind that for all lists of 0, 1, .... N, the same results will be outputed. This is expected and fine, I just want the results to be the input shuffled around.

For example: N = 10. I call the function 10 times with: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and it might return 7, 1, 5, 2, 9, 8, 3, 0, 4, 6.

I found this function :

```
function perm( x )
{
    return x * 833 % N;
}
```

Where 833 can be any large-ish prime number.
This makes good-ish results but they are always with a repeating pattern. See for N = 16:
0
3
6
9
12
15
2
5
8
11
14
1
4
7
10
13

Imagine it looks like 3 shark fins.
Basically my question is, how do I make a function that does what I have described but with a more chaotic shuffle?

I CANNOT pregenerate a permutation of 0, 1...N.

Comment: Your restriction on pregenerating a permutation seems very arbitrary. If you want a deterministic answer, the function you want is essentially just that - a complicated way of describing a pregenerated permutation. If you're allowed a source of randomness, you should just look up any old shuffling algorithm. If you want a deterministic version, you could do the same thing but provide the algorithm with a predetermined seed.

Comment: Until you can give a rigorous definition of what conditions make it an acceptable shuffle, it is not really a mathematical problem.

Comment: @Thomas I am unsure what variable degrees of shuffle are. Lets put it this way: if you put the values into a chart, you wouldn't see a visual pattern, like can immediately see in my formula.

user73445 X is the nr of already generated values. It represents the number of entries in my database. There is nowhere to put the pregenerated characters, thus when I add another entry in my database, I get the nr of existing entries, generate using the F(x) I seek, and add the entry with the result.

Comment: But again "visible pattern" is not a mathematical definition. You can't solve a problem without a definition. Even in pure randomness, humans see patterns.

Comment: Bad case: 1, 20, 6, 26, 5, 34..... This is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to pick some big number $n$, say of order $N!/2$.  Use that to find the $n^{\text{th}}$ lexicographic permutation of $N$.  The first number is $\lfloor \frac n{(N-1)!} \rfloor$.  Then form $n'=n-\lfloor \frac n{(N-1)!} \rfloor$  The second number is the $\lfloor \frac {n'}{(N-2)!} \rfloor$th one of what is left (so increment by $1$ if higher than the first).  Keep going, reducing the factorial in the denominator by $1$ each time.